# Critical dependency: the request of a dependency (sequelize) is an expression in next.js

Tags: javascript, typescript, database, sequelize.js, next.js13

I'm trying to use sequelize in Nextjs13 to connect my api routes to my database and keep getting errors "Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression"

```
import * as pg from 'pg';
import { Sequelize } from "sequelize";

const connectionString = process.env.CONNECTION_STRING as string

const sequelize = new Sequelize(connectionString,  {
    dialectModule: pg,
    dialectOptions: {
        ssl: {
            rejectUnauthorized: false
        }
    }
})

export default sequelize
```

```
import sequelize from "../database";
import { DataTypes } from "sequelize";

const User = sequelize.define('user', {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    username: DataTypes.STRING,
    hashedPass: DataTypes.STRING
})

export default User;
```

I tried using these in and importing user into my `register/route.ts` in order to create a user, but it keeps telling me there is issues with the sequelize dependency>

Answer (score 8):

In my case, the cause was next config issue.
My code is:

```js
import process from 'process';
import { Sequelize } from "sequelize";

const config = {
    "username": "postgres",
    "password": "xxx",
    "database": "xxxxx",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "dialect": "postgres"
  };
let sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);
```

next.js version is 13.4.12, sequelize version is 6.31.0.
I could fix the issue by adding this setting into next config

```js
   experimental: {
      serverComponentsExternalPackages: ['sequelize'],
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

change `import` to `require`(load moudle synchronously), the warning should dismiss, works for me with `next 13.4.1`

```js
import * as pg from 'pg';
import { Sequelize } from "sequelize";
```

```js
const pg = require('pg');
const { Sequelize } = require('sequelize');
```